# JavaScript keyup and onload to calculate a field total

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, keyup

I am calculating two text inputs using JavaScript. It works with keyup. Ie when typing, the balance calculates in realtime. However, I want the total to calculate and display not only on keyup, but onload as well, so for when I load the page, that it calculates the fields already.

This is my current working javascript code for keyup only

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("keyup", function() {
var sum = 0;
$(".totalCal").each(function(){
    sum += +$(this).val();
});
$("#total").val(sum);

document.getElementById('grandTotal').innerHTML = sum.toFixed(2);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/L2s5yoth/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="0" class="totalCal"><br />
<input type="text" value="1" class="totalCal"><br />
<input type="text" value="2" class="totalCal"><br />
<input type="text" value="3" class="totalCal"><br />
<div id="total">0</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(calculate);   
$(document).on("keyup", calculate);

function calculate() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".totalCal").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $("#total").html(sum);
}
```

Comment: Anytime, Derick. The innerHTML seems to update in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L2s5yoth/1/

Answer (score 1):

I think that something like this would be work

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(calculate());   
    $(document).on("keyup", calculate());

    function calculate() {
        var sum = 0;
        $(".totalCal").each(function(){
            sum += +$(this).val();
        });
        $("#total").val(sum);

        document.getElementById('grandTotal').innerHTML = sum.toFixed(2);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Working, WONDERFUL. And THANK YOU. Just one thing though, the inner HTML wont update. Perhaps there is a way to assign a variable to the calculated answer and display it as inner html? Thank you for your help!